# Is my performance affected by invisible items?

Tags: particles, drivers

I am making a video and I am planning to have a particle emitter to shoot lasers from my spaceship. My theory is to somehow keep it going endlessly, but control its invisibility somehow, perhaps with drivers.

Would it still be running in the background while invisible, thereby affecting the performance?

Comment: you are talking about the blender game engine or making a video?

Comment: making a video, sorry should have said that

Answer (score 0):

Like is it still running in the background while invisible?
-> if an object is in the renderlayer, whatever the color (even invisibility) blender will still compute it ( so it will decrease performance).
If you don't need this object you can put in in another renderlayer that you don't use.

but control it's invisibility somehow
-> you can use a keyframe on the color of the material to make visible/invisble at the moment you want

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes, but to varying extents, and it depends.

Any object that is has "display in viewports" enabled will have its geometry evaluated.  That includes things like armature modifiers, fcurves and modifiers, constraints, even if the objects are not rendered or are hidden (hiding is *not* the same as disabling display in viewports.)

If you have any objects that are displayed in viewports, that depend on an object that is *not* displayed in viewports, those undisplayed objects will still get evaluated.  This includes dependencies on the basis of disabled modifiers or muted constraints.

Any objects that have "display in renders" disabled may still be evaluated, costing performance, but they will not cost *as much* performance.  Even though their modifier stacks/fcurves/constraints will be evaluated, their vertices will not be transformed for the render, they will not play a part in BVH generation, and their faces won't be rendered.  Basically, as long as they are disabled in renders, your CPU will still compute bits of them, but your GPU won't even know they exist.